# Using JavaScript in typescript with JQuery

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular

I am trying to use a 3rd party library ([autonumeric](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric)) with Typescript + Angular2.

I have tried the following

```
/// <reference path="/typings/main/ambient/jquery/index.d.ts" />
declare interface JQuery {
    autoNumeric: any;
}
```

and on `init` I am trying to use it.

```
ngOnInit() {
        $('selector').autoNumeric('init', {options});
    }
```

But when I compile, I am getting the following error.

> error TS2339: Property 'autoNumeric' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

I am not getting where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated

**NOTE**

I have included the autonumeric.js in the index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it exactly like you and it works fine. You should create definition file to extend `JQuery` interface and add reference to `*.d.ts` file to `main.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/declarations.d.ts" />
```

where `declarations.d.ts` contains:

```
declare interface JQuery {
    autoNumeric: any;
}
```

Comment: hm,  try this one `jQuery('selector').autoNumeric('init', {options});`

Comment: i've update the answer, you have to put this declaration to separate `*.d.ts` file, otherwise it will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just kept it simple and declared `jQuery` as an `any`

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'jquery-integration',
    templateUrl: './components/jquery-integration/jquery-integration.html'
})
export class JqueryIntegration implements OnInit {
    elementRef: ElementRef;
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).draggable({containment:'#draggable-parent'});
    }
}
```

Here is the full example: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0